# Generate random matrix in numpy without rows of all 1's

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am generating a random matrix with

```
np.random.randint(2, size=(5, 3))
```

that outputs something like

```
[0,1,0],
[1,0,0],
[1,1,1],
[1,0,1],
[0,0,0]
```

How do I create the random matrix with the condition that each row cannot contain all `1`'s? That is, each row can be `[1,0,0]` or `[0,0,0]` or `[1,1,0]` or `[1,0,1`] or `[0,0,1`] or `[0,1,0]` or `[0,1,1]` but **cannot** be `[1,1,1]`.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: I assume you don't only want this to work when making an array of size `5 x 3`. In general, do you want random arrays where each row can't be all 1s or where the total number of 1s in each row can't exceed some constant value? Does this only need to work for 2D arrays?

Comment: Yes, it's only work for 2D arrays, for the size can 5x3, 6x3 etc but at an array don't have value like `[1,1,1] `

Comment: Is the number of columns (the size of the second dimension) always 3?

Comment: I don't see how the question is unclear.  The checked answer isn't so great, but that doesn't seem to warrant closure.

Comment: @DanielF 100% with you on that one. The title could be improved, though.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this solution using `sum()`:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.random.randint(2, size=(5, 3))
for i, entry in enumerate(array):
    if entry.sum() == 3:
        while True:
            new = np.random.randint(2, size=(1, 3))
            if new.sum() == 3:
                continue
            break
        array[i] = new

print(array)
```

Good luck my friend!

Comment: This won't necessarily work. When you call `np.random.randint` the second time, you can still generate a row of all 1s. You'll need to use a `while` loop - see my answer for an example, which also resamples all necessary rows at once.

Comment: Very simple to check if the new entry is acceptable. It's fixed.

Comment: This fixed the first problem, but you've introduced a second - you don't actually overwrite the original row with `new`.

Comment: Actually I do. My solution is very elegant.

Comment: thanks for your help, but your code still generate [1,1,1]

Comment: I made a mistake with the == sign, it works now! Please try it Ipung!

Comment: wow, this is more answers has solve my problems, thanks in advance darshvader

Answer (score 7):

Here's an interesting approach:

```
rows = np.random.randint(7, size=(6, 1), dtype=np.uint8)
np.unpackbits(rows, axis=1)[:, -3:]
```

Essentially, you are choosing integers 0-6 for each row, ie 000-110 as binary. 7 would be 111 (all 1's). You just need to extract binary digits as columns and take the last 3 digits (your 3 columns) since the output of `unpackbits` is 8 digits.

Output:

```
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Clever, I hadn't thought of that! And you could generalize this to any number of columns too by using `high = 2 ** n_cols - 1` where `high` is the upper bound for `randint`, yes? Though I suppose that only works until you have too many columns to fit in, e.g., an int64.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for reminding again that there's always a radically new way to approach any problem !

Comment: @Nathan `unpackbits` seems to be restricted to 8-bit integers, but you could replace that function with your own to expand it beyond 8 digits/columns. Not sure if there's already an alternative within numpy to do this.

Comment: @fountainhead Definitely makes coding more interesting!

Comment: I expect that as the number of bits exceeds 8, we run into platform-specific uncertainties about representation, such as big-endian vs little endian

Comment: Nice, indeed it is a great approach to simplify this problem

Answer (score 4):

If you always have 3 columns, one approach is to explicitly list the possible rows and then choose randomly among them until you have enough rows:

```py
import numpy as np

# every acceptable row
choices = np.array([
    [1,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [1,1,0],
    [1,0,1],
    [0,0,1],
    [0,1,0],
    [0,1,1]
])

n_rows = 5
# randomly pick which type of row to use for each row needed
idx = np.random.choice(range(len(choices)), size=n_rows)

# make an array by using the chosen rows
array = choices[idx]
```

If this needs to generalize to a large number of columns, it won't be practical to explicitly list all choices (even if you create the choices programmatically, the memory is still an issue; the number of possible rows grows exponentially in the number of columns). Instead, you can create an initial matrix and then just resample any unacceptable rows until there are none left. I'm assuming that a row is unacceptable if it consists only of 1s; it would be easy to adapt this to the case where the threshold is any number of 1s, though.

```py
n_rows = 5
n_cols = 4

array = np.random.randint(2, size=(n_rows, n_cols))
all_1s_idx = array.sum(axis=-1) == n_cols
while all_1s_idx.any():
    array[all_1s_idx] = np.random.randint(2, size=(all_1s_idx.sum(), n_cols))
    all_1s_idx = array.sum(axis=-1) == n_cols
```

Here we just keep resampling all unacceptable rows until there are none left. Because all of the necessary rows are resampled at once, this should be quite efficient. Additionally, as the number of columns grows larger, the probability of a row having all 1s decreases exponentially, so efficiency shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Overly complicated solution, using sum() is much more elegant.

Comment: Thanks Nathan for the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

@busybear beat me to it but I'll post it anyway, as it is a bit more general:

```
def not_all(m, k):
    if k>64 or sys.byteorder != 'little':
        raise NotImplementedError
    sample = np.random.randint(0, 2**k-1, (m,), dtype='u8').view('u1').reshape(m, -1)
    sample[:, k//8] <<= -k%8                                                        
    return np.unpackbits(sample).reshape(m, -1)[:, :k]
```

For example:

```
>>> sample = not_all(1000000, 11)
# sanity checks
>>> unq, cnt = np.unique(sample, axis=0, return_counts=True)
>>> len(unq) == 2**11-1
True
>>> unq.sum(1).max()
10
>>> cnt.min(), cnt.max()
(403, 568)
```

And while I'm at hijacking other people's answers here is a streamlined version of @Nathan's acceptance-rejection method.

```
def accrej(m, k):
    sample = np.random.randint(0, 2, (m, k), bool)
    all_ones, = np.where(sample.all(1))
    while all_ones.size:
        resample = np.random.randint(0, 2, (all_ones.size, k), bool)
        sample[all_ones] = resample
        all_ones = all_ones[resample.all(1)]
    return sample.view('u1')
```